# How to attach a txt file using the current email library?

Tags: python, email, smtplib

Many of the answers related to this question correspond to an old documentation from the email library ([EMAIL OLD DOC.](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email-examples.html)). I want to send an email attaching a txt file with the current documentation ([EMAIL DOC.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)).

**EXAMPLE:**

```py
import smtplib, ssl
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.utils import formatdate            


def mail_info(user, message):
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['From'] = user
    msg['To'] = user
    msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
    msg['Subject'] = 'Subject'
    msg.add_attachment(message, maintype='text', subtype='txt')
    return msg

def send_mail(message, user, password, smtp_mail, port):
    msg = mail_info(user, message)
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(host=smtp_mail, port=port, context=context) as server:
        '''conect to the server'''
        server.login(user=user, password=password)
        server.sendmail(from_addr=user, to_addrs=user, msg=msg.as_string())    

message = 'This is my email'
with open('filename.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.write(message)
    attachment = f.read().encode('utf-8')
    send_mail(message=attachment, user=user, password=password, 
              smtp_mail=smtp, port=port)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use MIMEMultipart as your container, and attach everything to it, so try something like this:

```py
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email import encoders

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))

with open(filename, "r") as attach:
    part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload(attach.read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header(
        "Content-Disposition",
        f"attachment; filename= {filename}",
    )
    msg.attach(part)

...

send_mail(message=msg, user=user, password=password, smpt_mail=smpt, port=port)
```

Comment: just to remember you need to add `from email import encoders` and you don't need to user`msg.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))` to make it work

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send a text file as an attachment using the [EmailMessage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html#email.message.EmailMessage) class, it's done like this:

```py
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg['subject'] = 'Here is a text attachment'
msg['from'] = 'me@example.com'
msg['to'] = 'you@example.com'

# Set message body.
msg.set_content('Hello\nand\ngoodbye')

# Add the attachment
with open('foo.txt', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
msg.add_attachment(data, maintype='text', subtype='plain')

with smtplib.SMTP('localhost', 1025) as s:
    s.send_message(msg)
```

If we run the SMTP debug server, listening on port 1025 in another terminal

```
 python3 -m smtpd -n -c DebuggingServer localhost:1025
```

we can see the resulting message

```
b'subject: Here is a text attachment'
b'from: me@example.com'
b'to: you@example.com'
b'MIME-Version: 1.0'
b'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="===============4749170073857401373=="'
b'X-Peer: ::1'
b''
b'--===============4749170073857401373=='
b'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"'
b'Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit'
b''
b'Hello'
b'and'
b'goodbye'
b''
b'--===============4749170073857401373=='
b'Content-Type: text/plain'
b'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64'
b'MIME-Version: 1.0'
b'Content-Disposition: attachment'
b''
b'VGhpcyBpcyB0aGUgYXR0YWNobWVudAo='
b''
b'--===============4749170073857401373==--'
```

Comment: (this is along way of saying, your subtype should have been "plain")

Comment: this is close of what I'm looking for, but the email sent will not have the txt file attached, but will have the content of the file written

Comment: " the email sent will not have the txt file attached, but will have the content of the file written" -> can you clarify this?  The question is "how to attach txt file" - what exactly do you want?  Perhaps you could edit your question to show an example.